# IOS virtual channel tutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c, rdp, virtual-channel

I am writing an application for iPad that will need to communicate to a server through a TS connection I have(the application) to able to pass RDP Settings and data to server. Virtual Channels seems to be exactly what I need but Microsoft's documentation leaves very much to be desired.

Does anyone know of good tutorials or just some examples I could use to help me. Preferred language is Objective-C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you writing an RDP Client, or integrating with an existing one?

Comment: I'm no written an RDP Client, I integrated an existing one which is call iFreeRDP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work iFreeRDP must have some kind of plug-in architecture allowing you to run custom code and open a virtual channel (this seems unlikely given Apple's strict policies on sandboxing, but I may be wrong).

If this is possible, you'd want to write a plug in as in the following article (assuming iFreeRDP uses the same interfaces for plug ins as the traditional Terminal Service Client on Windows):
[How to Write a Terminal Services Add-in in Pure C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16374/How-to-Write-a-Terminal-Services-Add-in-in-Pure-C)

Although the article uses C#, the key functions from the Terminal Services API are used which are where the complexity lies.